# How can we update/concatenate whereHas condition in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hi everyone Could someone let me know how can we update/concatenate  **whereHas** condition in Laravel

Example#1.

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'code%');
});

if($request->has('user_id') && $request->user_id >0){
   $posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function (Builder $query) use($request) {
    $query->where('user_id', $request->user_id);
   });
}

$posts->get();
```

I know I can combine both whereHas quires in one like this

Example#2

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function (Builder $query) use($request) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'code%');
    if($request->has('user_id') && $request->user_id >0){
       $query->where('user_id', $request->user_id);
    }
});
```

But I dont want this way I want to adopt first example in my project. Could you please let me know if this possible

Comment: Can you explain more clear "But I dont want this way I want to adopt first example in my project"?

Comment: in first example the final query will be
select * from posts and exists (select * from comments where content like "code%" ) and exists(select * from comments where user_id=xxxxx)

Comment: in 2nd example the final query will be
select * from posts and exists (select * from comments where content like "code%"  and   user_id=xxxxx)

Comment: I want to generate 2nd example query from first example code

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to operate on the same query. You can keep adding conditions to your query, by saving the query builder as an variable, like $query = `Post::where('title', 'something');`.

The query builder also has a method called `when()`, that is conditional syntactic sugar for the if statement you have made.

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'code%');
})->when($request->has('user_id') && $request->user_id > 0, function ($query) use ($request) {
    $query->whereHas('comments', function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
         $query->where('user_id', $request->user_id);
    });
})->get();
```